# How can I count the number of occurrences of another field in a BigQuery Select statement?

Tags: select, count, google-bigquery

I have the following example data:

| id | domain |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |
| 2 | example |
| 3 | test |
| 4 | main |
| 5 | main |
| 6 | test |

What I want to do in a Select statement is to end with the following:

| id | domain | domain_occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | 3 |
| 2 | example | 1 |
| 3 | test | 3 |
| 4 | main | 2 |
| 5 | main | 2 |
| 6 | test | 3 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `count(*) over (partition by domain)`:

```
select 
  *,
  count(*) over (partition by domain) as domain_occurencies
from mytabel
```